# Html.DropDownListFor always returning value '0' regardless of whatever selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to bind an enum `AgeRange` using `Html.DropDownListFor` but regardless of whatever I'm choosing from View page, Controller is getting a value '0'. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

EDIT: Controller code in place.

Enum Class:

```
public enum AgeRange
{
  Unknown = -1,    
  [Description("< 3 days")]
  AgeLessThan3Days = 1,    
  [Description("3-6 days")]
  AgeBetween3And6 = 2,    
  [Description("6-9 days")]
  AgeBetween6And9 = 3,    
  [Description("> 9 days")]
  AgeGreaterThan9Days = 4
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
      model => model.Filter.AgeRangeId,
      @Html.GetEnumDescriptions(typeof(AgeRange)),
      new { @class = "search-dropdown", name = "ageRangeId" }
)
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Search(int? ageRangeId)
{
   var filter = new CaseFilter { AgeRangeId = (AgeRange)(ageRangeId ?? 0) };
}
```

Comment: I suggested that you needed a closing bracket so I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close...

I'd suggest following along with [this guy](http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-method-extension/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to write an extension method for your selectlist to work.

I use this

```
public static SelectList ToSelectList<TEnum>(this TEnum enumeration) where TEnum : struct
{
  //You can not use a type constraints on special class Enum.
  if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
    throw new ArgumentException("TEnum must be of type System.Enum");
  var source = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum));
  var items = new Dictionary<object, string>();
  foreach (var value in source)
  {
    FieldInfo field = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
    DisplayAttribute attrs = (DisplayAttribute)field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false).First();
    items.Add(value, attrs.GetName());
  }
  return new SelectList(items, Constants.PropertyKey, Constants.PropertyValue, enumeration);
}
```